# how to create a calculated table having distinct values from one column in DAX inside Power BI Desktop

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want create a new table having distinct values from the column **[Delivery Date Key]** from the table **Fact_Sale.**

**[Delivery Date Key]** columns have below mentioned values

2013-01-12

2013-01-15

2013-04-19

2013-04-18

Now I want to create a new table having the below values, considering only year and month. Date will be hardcoded as 1. Because want to **group sales by Month and Year** and not date.. So the final rows of the new table will be

2013-01-01

2013-04-01

I am trying to use the below DAX query but  it seems that DISTINCT does not accept year function:

```
Date1 = DISTINCT(date(year('Fact Sale'[Delivery Date Key]),month('Fact Sale'[Delivery Date Key]),1))
```

I have added the image of error also.. Is there another way to deal this situation. I am stuck since 3 days on it..

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach that might help - I have added a few more dates just to be sure that the output is correct.

[image]

The DAX formula that I am using:

```
Date1 = 
    var t = DISTINCT('Fact_Sale'[Delivery Date Key])
    var Result = SELECTCOLUMNS(t, "Adjusted Date", DATE(YEAR(Fact_Sale[Delivery Date Key]), MONTH(Fact_Sale[Delivery Date Key]), 1))
return
    DISTINCT(Result)
```

...and the final result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case the requirement was to create a **distinct list of IP addresses** from one of the columns in a Table.

I was trying to create a table in **Transform Data** screen, in **Power Query**.

Here's the code that worked for me.

```
= let
    Source = #"TABLENAME",
    firstCol  = #"TABLENAME"[Client Ip],
    IP = List.Distinct(firstCol),
    #"DistinctIP" = Table.FromColumns({IP}, {"IP"})
in
    #"DistinctIP"
```